# How can I use Persian DatePicker in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

I want to use a Persian datepicker component (by Syncfusion) in ASP.NET Core. I couldn't find any way to use the jalali calendar in ASP.NET Core when using the Syncfusion component.

Note: I was able to use the Persian calendar in Blazor by setting culture to `fa`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("fa");
```

But this solution does not work in ASP.NET Core. There is also a [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/172407/bug-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-objectinline-editing-and) for this purpose in the site's own documents, but unfortunately the answer is not correct.

Is there any way to use the Persian datepicker in ASP.NET Core Syncfusion component?